# Spring MVC not Displaying Text Correctly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Attempting to make a hello world page from Spring MVC.

Here is my `/WeeklyPickems/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lucentdigital.controller"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Here is my `/WeeklyPickems/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WeeklyPickemsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WeeklyPickemsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Archetype Created W eb Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Here is my `/WeeklyPickems/src/main/java/com/lucentdigital/controller/HelloController.java`

```
package com.lucentdigital.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

        return "hello";

    }

}
```

When navigating to `http://localhost:8080`, the browser correctly renders `/WeeklyPickems/src/main/webapp/index.jsp` but navigating to `http://localhost:8080/WeeklyPickems/greeting.html`, I it used to display a 404 error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Now I have updated my PATH and it all works but still not displaying the correct "Hello World". I have the following in `/WeeklyPickems/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${greeting}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the webpage is displaying the word "${greeting}" on the page.
What do I need to change to what file to actually display "Hello World" in the `H1` tag?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the controller loading at the startup process ?

Comment: I needed to add $JAVA_HOME as an environmental variable. But now I am getting the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet name is not related with you servlet context.

I believe that in this case, based in your question, your context is `/`.

The first thing to do is change your `url-mapping` from:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WeeklyPickemsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WeeklyPickemsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After that call `http://localhost:8080/greeting` as described in your controller.

Comment: When I make that change, `http://localhost:8080` does not even load (and neither does `/greeting`, `/greeting.html`, `/WeeklyPickems/greeting` or `/WeeklyPickems/greeting.html`)

Comment: Do you have the `<welcome-file-list>` tag mappend in your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing adding `isELIgnored="false"` to the `page`. This is the resulting jsp file:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${greeting}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```